# Problems with decoding from command prompt [python]

Tags: python, utf8-decode

I have the following problem. I have a german text saved in .txt UTF-8 format, and I'd like to  print it out with python. Here's my code:

```
txt = open(filename, 'r').read()
print txt.decode('utf-8-sig')
```

It works perfectly in IDLE, but when I save my code and run it from the command prompt, it raises error, specifically:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: cha
racter maps to <undefined>
```

In my particular case, the text is "gemäßigt", and in the beginning of .py code I put something like

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig -*-
```

By the way, my OS is Windows, in Russian. Does anybody have an idea what is my problem?

Best,
Alex

Comment: What do you get when you `import sys` and then `sys.stdout.encoding` in the console?

Comment: That's your problem, that codepage doesn't support German special characters. What do you get when you try the above command in IDLE?

Comment: In IDLE I get exactly the same word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console uses the [DOS codepage 866](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_866) which doesn't have the character symbols for `ä` or `ß`, causing the error.

You could try `.encoding('cp866', errors='replace')` your string before output, replacing all the characters not supported by your terminal by `?`s.

Comment: Somehow, it does not work. I'll goolge later on again, and write down solution if I'll find some. Many thanks for your suggestions how to solve it!

Comment: Maybe I was unclear; you first need to decode it from UTF-8, then encode that to cp866: `print txt.decode('utf-8-sig').encode('cp866', errors='replace')`. Did you try it that way?

Comment: @Alekz112: if you don't need to output both latin and cyrillic characters, you can try changing the codepage (`chcp 850` at the DOS prompt, then `python.exe myscript.py`). That at least allows you to output words like "gemäßigt".

Answer (score 0):

Is your text in UTF-8 or utf-8-sig ? It's not exaclty the same.
Here you can learn the difference.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode

You can also open text file already decoded with

```
import codecs
txt = codecs.open(filename,'r',"utf-8-sig").read()
```

I think Tim is correct about the console problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected console problem, I just can't figure out how to fix it